# retail hardware SHA256d hash rates

Tags: hashpower, sha256

Obviously it hasn't been profitable to mine bitcoin on retail hardware for years at this point.

Nevertheless, I'm curious.

Does anybody have any benchmarks on what the hash rates for retail hardware would be today? Preferably on an x86 chip?

Comment: Mine for what coin? It depends..

Comment: @Willtech good question! Just updated the question to make it clear it was about bitcoin :)

Comment: @pebwindkraft thanks for that, that's helpful. The hashing rates referenced there are for scrypt though and here I'm looking SHA256d rates here. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular Ah yea, I saw that but that question simply points users in the direction of tools that can be used to determine the hash rate of your hardware, it doesn't supply any actual numbers.